# Where to get "sw-context-token" in Shopware6 using store API

Tags: shopware

[https://shopware.stoplight.io/docs/store-api/storeapi.json/paths/~1account~1login/post](https://shopware.stoplight.io/docs/store-api/storeapi.json/paths/%7E1account%7E1login/post)

Says you will get "sw-context-token" after login but this API response throws the following error.

```json
"errors": [
        {
            "status": "400",
            "code": "FRAMEWORK__MISSING_REQUEST_PARAMETER",
            "title": "Bad Request",
            "detail": "Parameter \"sw-context-token\" is missing.",
            "meta": {
                "parameters": {
                    "parameterName": "sw-context-token"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like an issue in Shopware core. As a workaround, you can just pass that header `sw-context-token` in your request with an empty value.

Comment: What I found for Store API is to add any random string as sw-context-token header when calling the /login endpoint. For any request after that, use the token that was returned by the login request.

Answer (score 2):

As posted before, this looks like a bug.

Also a header like

```
sw-context-token: dummy
```

works flawlessly.

Either the API documentation should be updated or the request should not fail, if the header is not set.

Digging deeper, we find that the error is thrown here:

\Shopware\Core\Framework\Routing\SalesChannelRequestContextResolver::resolve

```
    if (
        $this->contextTokenRequired($request) === true
        && !$request->headers->has(PlatformRequest::HEADER_CONTEXT_TOKEN)
    ) {
        throw new MissingRequestParameterException(PlatformRequest::HEADER_CONTEXT_TOKEN);
    }
```

There seems to be a possibility to set requests as not-requiring a context token (if the request does not have the `PlatformRequest::ATTRIBUTE_CONTEXT_TOKEN_REQUIRED` attribute)

Removing [this annotation](https://github.com/shopware/core/blob/1c199e42a601177c25667c909144e44afecf67a0/Checkout/Customer/SalesChannel/LoginRoute.php#L37) basically works, but I am not sure, if that is the right solution.

I recommend posting this problem on https://issues.shopware.com